# How to get a property value from a nested class?

Tags: c#, oop, inner-classes, encapsulation, abstraction

Hello i have problem with get nested class property value. I want

```
class Car
{

  string name;
  string model;

  class Engine
  {
    public string engineNumber;

    public Engine(string engineNumber)
    {
      this.engineNumber = engineNumber;
    }

  }

  public Car(string name, string model, string engineNumber)
  {

    this.name = name;
    this.model = model;
    Engine e1 = new engine(engineNumber)
  }

}
```

In this code I try write `Console.Write(c1.e1.engineNumber);`in Main class. It is possible get `engineNumber` value?

Comment: What is `c1`?  Your code example is incomplete.  Also, you should probably be using properties instead of fields

Comment: Why do you have `Engine` defined a a private inner class?  Also you don't do anything with the `Engine` you create in the `Car` constructor.  I'd suggest moving `Engine` out of `Car` and adding a `Engine` property to `Car`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways to accomplish it, here is mine :), the trick is to differentiate class declaration from class implementation.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    var c = new Car("Name", "Model", "Engine");
    Console.WriteLine(c.engine.engineNumber);
  }

  class Car
  {
    string name;
    string model;
    public Engine engine;

    public Car(string name, string model, string engineNumber)
    {
      this.name = name;
      this.model = model;
      this.engine = new Engine(engineNumber);
    }
  }

  class Engine
  {
    public string engineNumber;
    public Engine(string engineNumber)
    {
      this.engineNumber = engineNumber;
    }
  } 
}
```

You can see it running here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/66lGn6

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I meant :)

Answer (score 1):

You generally don't want to nest class definitions the way you did.  What if you had a car that could use a different kind of engine?  Like, say, a 4-liter vs. a 2-liter?  Or normally aspirated vs. turbo charged?  What you might want to do instead is pass in the `Engine` as a parameter to the `Car`.

Regarding your actual problem of obtaining values from these objects, you also need to define how values can be obtained and/or changed.  A constructor does the initial work, but what if the `Engine` or `Car` have values that need to be changed or obtained during the program's lifestyle?  You need accessors.

```
public class Car
{
    public string name { get; private set; }
    public string model { get; private set; }
    public Engine engine { get; private set; }

    public Car(string name, string model, Engine engine)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.model = model;
        this.engine = engine;
    }
}

class Engine
{
    public string number { get; private set; }
    // other values as necessary

    public Engine(string number)
    {
        this.number = number;
    }
}

var newCar = new Car('Volvo', 'Hatchback', new Engine('someNumber'));
var engineNumber = newCar.engine.number;
```

In this example, you can obtain the data you want by referencing an object property (`get`), but you won't be able to change that data in the same way (`private set`).  Instead, you'd need to make object methods (read: functions, if you're new to OOP) to explicitly change those values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will be able.

But the code you provide losts `Engine e1` just after creation since you don't store it at the `Car` class level.

And the class `Engine` is private, it should be public.

And its constructor should be `internal protected` to allow only a `Car` to create its `Engine`: `internal` to prevent other assembly to be able to create one, and `protected` to allow derived classes even in another assembly to create it.

You can try something like that by changing the getters/setters as you want (I made them public/private, so after creation they can't be mofified by external entities):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Car c1 = new Car("Toyota", "Model", "1");
  Console.WriteLine(c1.engine.engineNumber);
}

public class Car
{

  public class Engine
  {
    public string engineNumber { get; private set; }
    internal protected Engine(string engineNumber)
    {
      this.engineNumber = engineNumber;
    }
  }

  public string name { get; private set; }
  public string model { get; private set; }
  public Engine engine { get; private set; }

  public Car(string name, string model, string engineNumber)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.model = model;
    this.engine = new Engine(engineNumber);
  }

}
```

If you want to be able to change the engine if it is broken, then the class may be not nested.

Comment: Probably should point out that having a class inside a class is usually not the right approach, especially in this case where there seems no reason for it.

Comment: Probably depends on if a `Engine` is part of a larger Strategy... is an `Engine` really an interface, based on things like cylinders, aspiration, displacement, HP, etc.?  Does the underlying logic of how an `Engine` (or `IEngine`) works important?

Comment: Putting classes in their own files is generally the preferred way to structure things.  You are making a big assumption that the `Engine` class will never be needed by anything other than `Car` (and maybe OP is too).  This is why it seems like a good learning opportunity for the OP

Comment: The question I have asked is not about a specific problem. I'm just starting to learn with programming and I came up with the idea of ​​whether it is possible to do something like that, but in the documentation I couldn't answer the question